# MVC Membership & Profile Strategy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

Bear in mind, I have researched this and have found several articles, however, they are mostly old (like from 2008) so I am wanting more recent information pertaining to the latest version(s) of ASP.NET MVC.

I am using the Membership built-in thing to provide user registration, login and roles.

I want to use the profile functions, too.

I don't know how to create a profile and I can't find any articles on how to do this in MVC 3.  I found one using MVC 2, maybe it's the same, but I want to use the latest available methods.

Can someone show me a step by step solution to creating a profile?

I am considering using my own membership classes + forms authentication.  That way, creating profiles is as simple as assigning a foreign key...

What's the experts' opinion?

Please provide your answer in VB and not C# (I don't know why everyone writes me stuff in C#).

Thanks.

Edit:  Here is my Register function:

```
'
' POST: /Account/Register

<HttpPost()> _
Public Function Register(ByVal model As RegisterModel) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        ' Attempt to register the user
        Dim createStatus As MembershipCreateStatus
        Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, Nothing, Nothing, True, Nothing, createStatus)

        If createStatus = MembershipCreateStatus.Success Then
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, False)
            Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
        Else
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus))
        End If
    End If

    ' If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

Comment: The good reason for all these articles being old, is that nothing has been changed with membership, role and profile providers in ASP.NET since version 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would recommend against using the SQL Profile Provider (which is what you are using). Nothing has changed with profiles since MVC2 (or, for that matter, since it was introduced in webforms with .NET 2.0).

The reason is this: Profile data is stored as XML in the database, which makes it very difficult to use profile data outside of your app (meaning in a pure SQL query).

You're probably much better off creating profile fields in your database directly. This way you know which table / column the data is coming from, and can create views if you need to. Otherwise, you would have to parse a table column's XML to extract the profile data (which is what the ProfileCommon does in .NET).

**Reply to comments**

First of all, I was wrong about the property name. It is `ProviderUserKey`, not `ProviderKey`. However unless you want to store profile properties for anonymous users, you could just as easily use `MembershipUser.UserName` as your FK value, since it will also be unique.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
    var membershipUser = Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, 
        model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

    if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
    {
        var providerKeyObject = membershipUser.ProviderUserKey;
        var providerKeyGuid = (Guid)membershipUser.ProviderUserKey;
        // Use providerKeyGuid as a foreign key when inserting into a profile
        // table. You don't need a real db-level FK relationship between
        // your profile table and the aspnet_Users table. You can lookup this
        // Guid at any time by just getting the ProviderUserKey property of the
        // MembershipUser, casting it to a Guid, and executing your SQL.

        // Example using EF / DbContext
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var profile = new MyProfileEntity
            {
                UserId = providerKeyGuid, // assumes this property is a Guid
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
            };
            db.Set<MyProfileEntity>().Add(profile);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        // you could get the profile back out like this
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var profile = db.Set<MyProfileEntity>().SingleOrDefault(p => 
                p.UserId == (Guid)membershipUser.ProviderUserKey);
        }
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(membershipUser.UserName, false);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Here is an example using the UserName instead of the ProviderUserKey. I would recommend this approach if you are not storing profile info for anonymous users:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
    var membershipUser = Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, 
        model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

    if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
    {
        // Example using EF / DbContext
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var profile = new MyProfileEntity
            {
                // assumes this property is a string, not a Guid
                UserId = membershipUser.UserName,
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
            };
            db.Set<MyProfileEntity>().Add(profile);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        // you could get the profile back out like this, but only after the 
        // auth cookie is written (it populates User.Identity.Name)
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var profile = db.Set<MyProfileEntity>().SingleOrDefault(p => 
                p.UserId == User.Identity.Name);
        }
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(membershipUser.UserName, false);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: To go with this, you just need to take the UserId (a guid) from the aspnet_users table and place it in your own profile table as a FK reference.

Comment: @Chris, I believe you can get this guid at runtime from the MembershipUser.ProviderKey value. Also, if you want to store profile properties for anonymous users, you could use Request.AnonymousId, which is also a Guid, and also stored in aspnet_Users when you enable anonymous identification.

Comment: Exactly. Generally during runtime, we've just taken the logged in users ProviderKey and used that to access the user's custom profile table. Once we've done that we have the ability to now use any number of normalized tables for different collections such as phone numbers, addresses, etc.

Comment: To create the foreign key, I assume I do this at the register process.  I have edited my question with my register method.  What's the best way to create the foreign key to the other table?  I know this is a basic question, I am just wanting to do it the proper way.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1477388 I apologize but I don't know very much VB, but I think it would looks something like this: `Dim membershipUser as MembershipUser = Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, ...)`. This will get you an instance of the user. You can then invoke `membershipUser.ProviderKey` to get the FK value. However I think it is an object, so you would need to cast to a Guid, and I don't know how to cast in VB.

Comment: This is one thing I miss about PHP.  I could just do var_dump($membershipUser) and it would tell me all of the objects in the object.  If your code returns an instance of the user, couldn't I just call the field from the database?  I can't get into the database because it's MDF and visual studio only lets me connect to SDF via database explorer.  Maybe I should just try to create my own membership implementation?  What's your opinion?  I don't haveto reinvent the wheel; maybe I could use this http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/.  Thanks.

Comment: If we have too many more comments, this will go into chat. However I highly recommend **not** rolling your own membership implementation, and have answered <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A304832+membership">other questions here</a> to that effect. The `MembershipUser` instance already has all of the data you need, there is no need to hit the db directly. I could tell you how to do it in C#, but VB looks yucky to me, it's just a personal preference. As to your PHP comment, this is just something you get with a precompiled (C#) versus dynamically compiled (PHP) language.

Comment: Maybe if you can show me the C# I will be able to decipher what I should do in VB.  Please show me what you have in mind.

Comment: @danludwig:  Sorry to be a total newb, but I am wondering your strategy for creating the actual record.  Do I need to create a db context for the foreign key table?  How would you go about it?  Thank you.

Comment: The strategy for creating the record is up to you, you didn't mention anything in the question about what you were using for your app's db access (DbContext/EntityFramework, NHibernate, LightSpeed, ADO.NET, etc). If you are already using EF, you should not need a new DbContext. You can just add profile entity(ies) to your existing DbContext. I will update the original question with an EF example.

Comment: Thank you.  I am indeed using EF so this will help as I will try to convert it to VB.  Have a good day, danludwig!